# How to align components using Box in jetpack compose?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, box

I've been working on something for a few hours and I really can't believe I couldn't do it. I don't understand why it didn't happen. I want to place an image and text in the center and a button and text at the bottom, but I couldn't do it.
The image and text in the center will be one under the other in the form of Column and should appear right in the center. Buttons and texts at the bottom will still be in the form of columns one after the other.

**It looks like this.**

[image]

Hear is my code:

**BottomBar composable**

```
@Composable
fun BottomBar(
    navHostController: NavHostController,
    text: String,
    route: String?,
    enabled: Boolean,
    onClick: () -> Unit
) {


    Row(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.Bottom
    ) {

        DYTLoginAndContinueButton(
            text = text,
            navController = navHostController,
            route = route,
            enabled = enabled
        ) {
            onClick()
        }
    }


    Row(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.Bottom
    ) {
        Text(
            text = "do you have account",,
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(8.dp)
                .clickable {
                    navHostController.navigate(RegisterScreen.SignInRegisterScreen.route)
                },
            style = MaterialTheme.typography.h6,
            textAlign = TextAlign.Center
        )
        Text(
            text = "login",
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(8.dp)
                .clickable {
                    navHostController.navigate(RegisterScreen.SignInRegisterScreen.route)
                },
            style = MaterialTheme.typography.body1,
            color = DefaultDYTColor,
            textAlign = TextAlign.Center
        )
    }
}
```

**StartScreen Composable**

```
  @Composable
    fun StartScreen2(navHostController: NavHostController) {
    
        Scaffold(
            topBar = {
               //TopBar is coming hear
            },
            bottomBar = {
    
            },
            backgroundColor = Color.Transparent
        ) {
    
            Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
    
                Column(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),     
                    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
                ) {
                    Box(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .weight(1f)
                            .fillMaxWidth()
                            .wrapContentHeight()
                            .padding(horizontal = 16.dp),
                        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
                    ) {
                        VegetableImageAndText(
                            modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.BottomCenter),
                            text = "Good Food",
                            textStyle = MaterialTheme.typography.subtitle1
                        )
                    }
    
                    Box(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxWidth()
                            .wrapContentHeight()
                            .padding(bottom = 16.dp),
                        contentAlignment = Alignment.BottomCenter
                    ) {
    
                        BottomBar(
                            navHostController = navHostController,
                            text = "Let's start",
                            route = null,
                            enabled = true,
                            onClick = {}
                        )
                    }
    
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**VegetableImageAndText Composable**

```
@Composable
fun VegetableImageAndText(
    modifier:Modifier,
    text:String,
    textStyle: TextStyle
) {

    Column(
        modifier = modifier,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
       ) {

        Image(
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_vegetable),
            contentDescription = "")
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(5.dp))
        Text(
            text = text,
            style = textStyle)
    }
}
```

Comment: In `BottomBar` you have 2 rows, but they do not have a parent to align them. What is the expected design?

Comment: As you can see at the top, the button and the text overlap. I want the text to appear under the button, so I want a little padding in between.

Comment: If you want the text to appear below button, both the rows should be inside a Column

Comment: okeyi thanks I got it.